# Loop through posts that is promote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to loop through post that are on promoted. I have a method in my post model that I can access. How would I call it in this instance. For example here are my methods my post model.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
def promoted?
    subscriptions.present?
  end

  def self.promoted_posts
    Post.joins(:subscriptions).where(:subscriptions => {:is_active => true})
  end

  def self.not_promoted_posts
    Post.left_outer_joins(:subscriptions).where(:subscriptions => {:post_id => nil})
  end

  def self.ordered_posts
    Post.promoted_posts + Post.not_promoted_posts
  end
end
```

Here is my view. I would like to loop through all the posts that are promoted which is the method "def promoted?" in my model

```
<% @posts.take(6).each do |post| %>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="featured-box">
          <figure>
            <%= link_to image_tag(post.images.first, class: 'img-fluid'), post %>
          </figure>
          <div class="feature-content">
            <div class="product">
              <p><%= post.category.name %> / <%= post.subcategory.name %></p>
            </div>
            <h4><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>
            <ul class="address">
              <li>
                Ad#: <%= post.ad_number %>
              </li>
              <li>
                posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago
              </li>
              <li>
                <%= post.state%> , <%= post.city.downcase %>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="listing-bottom">
              <h3 class="price float-left">$<%= post.price%></h3>
              <%= link_to 'Feature Ad', post, class: 'btn-verified float-right', style: 'color: red;' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use your `promoted?` method instead of `promoted_posts`? What is `@posts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are desperately in need of using the promoted, you can try

```
Post.all.find_all(&:promoted?)
```

which is short notation of

```
Post.all.find_all do |post|
    post.promoted?
end
```

which is kinda n+1 query and opting it while you can just use

```
Post.joins :subscriptions
```

is a fail.

Comment: When I try "Post.all.find_all(&:promoted)" in my show action in my posts controller I get an error "undefined method `promoted' for #<Post:0x00007fd9a0f1c788> Did you mean? promoted?"

Comment: I missed a "?" :)